# Can I skip the sender's email?

Tags: javascript, .net

I want to send an email without adding a sender's email or from field.  is this possible? or can I at least use a name instead of an email.  Thank you.

Comment: I don't think you can.  But you can always put an invalid email like `do.not.reply@company.com`

Comment: What is the link with any of the tag you provided ?

Comment: How is this related to Angular?

Comment: is spam as default....

Comment: You can, but it will be frowned upon (== probably treated as spam by other email services)

Comment: thanks everyone, i was wondering about that.

Comment: @JLRishe i removed the tag.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are using the `SmtpClient` and / or `MailMessage` classes then you should get an exception on `SmptClient.Send()` if the sender is null or empty:

The docs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient(v=vs.110).aspx